# Basic Memory Allocator Info needed- Hoard and SLAB

Tags: memory-management, hoard

Recently I have been reading about memory allocator, like Hoard and SLAB. However I didn't get few things:

a. Are these allocator managing physical memory or virtual memory. {If (your answer is Physical Memory) please read point b, else, read point c}

b. If they manage physical memory, since both these alloctor make use of per-CPU data structures, don't they end-up giving space from same physical page to different processes. For e.g. consider T1 starts on CPU C and request for an int. After this let T1 get preempted and T2 starts executing and it also ask for an int. Since our structures are per-CPU, is it not the case that we will end up satisfying both request from same physical page.

c. And if they manage virtual memory, then why we say that all data structures are per-CPU, rather we should say that they are per-process, because on every context switch we have to repopulate these data structures.